# Bootstrap Datepicker Read Wrong Year in Oracle Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I use oracle DB, and the format they used is `d-M-y` (in PHP), but in my datepicker, I'm already use option `dateFormat : d-M-yy`

The data showed perfectly until when I try to change, the year in datepicker showed `1917`, but when I insert the data, I'm surely choose `2017`

e.g :

```
Inserted : 18-NOV-17 (2017) // when inserted the year automatically in 2017
Showed in edit : 18-NOV-1917 // ????
```

I think it caused because datepicker can only read full format year (e.g 2017) which is mean he can't read format only last 2 year characters(17)

Maybe you guys can help me out.